# Emacs modeline and minor modes in a list

Tags: doom, mode-line-format

I use quite a lot of minor modes which quse huge places in the modeline so that I cannot see the major mode am I..  Is it possible to place all kind of minor modes in a sort of "dropdown" list in the modeline to gain place for other infos ?  I have also some free places after buffer position (like 22:72).  So mainly how can I customize the doom-modeline so that all info are displayed corectly ?
[image]

After enabled minions still the "major mode" truncated on right side .. and lot of unused space in the center ..
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide list of minor modes in mode-line](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3925/hide-list-of-minor-modes-in-mode-line)

Answer (score 3):

The [`minions`](https://melpa.org/#/minions) package does exactly this and is, apparently, compatible with the doom modeline.

Comment: That's fine but still have a lot of free space in the center of doom-modeline, do u known what kind of infos are displayed there ?  Can we put some kind of padding on left and right side of modeline ?

Comment: Sorry: I  use `smart-mode-line` which dies not have all that empty space...